# How to get these subequations to start at the same point?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subequations

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
v_{n+\frac{1}{2}}=v_n + \frac{1}{2}a(n) \Delta t
\end{equation}    
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
r_{n+\frac{1}{2}}=r_n + \frac{1}{2}v_n+\frac{1}{2}\Delta t
\end{equation}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
a(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{m}F(n+1/2)
\end{equation}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
v_{n+1}=v_n + a(n+1/2)\Delta t
\end{equation}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
r_{n+1}=r_n+v_{n+1}\Delta t
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Look at the empheq package.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `start at the same point`, alsao if you feel the need for adding `\vspace` between equations, then you are doing it wrong. Just use `align` from the `amsmath` package. I see no reason on using `empheq` here

Comment: Also haven't you already gotten several answers on http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327511/3929

Answer (score 2):

Don't use separate `equation` environments; instead, use a single `align` environment and start each line with a `&` character to indicate the common alignment point.

I would also like to recommend that you use either inline-fraction notation and/or `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` for some of the fractional terms in the equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
&v_{n+(1/2)}=v_n + \tfrac{1}{2}a(n) \Delta t\\
&r_{n+(1/2)}=r_n + \tfrac{1}{2}v_n+\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta t\\
&a(n+\tfrac{1}{2})=\tfrac{1}{m}F(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\\
&v_{n+1}=v_n + a(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\Delta t\\
&r_{n+1}=r_n+v_{n+1}\Delta t
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in 1a and 1b, is the subscript meant to be n+(1/2) or (n+1)/2?  as shown here, it's confusing, possibly ambiguous.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - The terms are always "1/2".

Comment: then it's best to include parentheses to remove any ambiguity.  see ellen swanson's [math into type](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf) on fractions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I've implemented your suggestions. :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Arrgh. Now it's done, though. (Incidentally, I thought that rules of precedence for arithmetical operations were unambiguous, but this belief may be unwarranted.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton glad to see that MiT is actually available online. I only have it in print.